# How to create a sequence in dbt with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I was wondering how to create a sequence using dbt (v1.0) and postgres ?
For example, if you try to create your sequence directly in a dbt model `my_model.sql` :

```sql
-- my_model.sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_column;

-- ... your model logic here

SELECT
    *
FROM
    FINAL
```

then run `dbt run --select my_model` and you will have the following error :

```
Postgres adapter: Postgres error: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 16: CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS
...
syntax error at or near "CREATE"
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [run_query](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) dbt jinja function with `set` to run SQL with dbt:

```sql
-- my_model.sql
{% set create_sequence_query %}
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_sequence;
{% endset %}
{% do run_query(create_sequence_query) %}

-- ... your model logic here

SELECT
    *
FROM
    FINAL
```

Comment: `{% do run_query(create_sequence_query) %}` would also work. And to run this as a hook you may need to add a `commit` to prevent the DDL from getting rolled back

Comment: Thank you, I changed 'set results' to 'do'.
Can you share an exemple with a hook and a commit please ?

Comment: `{% do run_query("CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_sequence; COMMIT") %}`